# Exception using mock library, python unit testing issue

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

- Windows 7 Professional (64 bit)
- Python 2.7.14 (2.7.14150 64 bit)
- mock 2.0.0

When I just run `python -c "import mock"` from command prompt (as an administrator) it yields Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mock\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    import mock.mock as _mock
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mock\mock.py", line 71, in <module>
    _v = VersionInfo('mock').semantic_version()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pbr\version.py", line 461, in semantic_version
    self._semantic = self._get_version_from_pkg_resources()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pbr\version.py", line 448, in _get_version_from_pkg_resources
    result_string = packaging.get_version(self.package)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pbr\packaging.py", line 755, in get_version
    name=package_name))
Exception: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository. It's also possible that there is a mismatch between the package name in setup.cfg and the argument given t
o pbr.version.VersionInfo. Project name mock was given, but was not able to be found.
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the exception message at the end: `Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository. It's also possible that there is a mismatch between the package name in setup.cfg and the argument given to pbr.version.VersionInfo. Project name mock was given, but was not able to be found.`

This seems to be an issue with `pbr` package. Have you tried to reinstall it or remove it to test if this fixes the issue (which would indicate you need to concetrate on `pbr`)?

Comment: @sophoros I uninstalled `pbr` and run `python -c "import mock"` again. It complained on missing `pbr`. It seems that this `pbr` library is a must for `mock`. Also, after installing `pbr` back. The same exception popped out!  Any new ideas?

Comment: Then I suggest that you check setup.cfg (maybe in the `%PATH%`) as pointed out in the message above. Maybe there indeed is a mismatch in versions for some reasons.

Comment: @sophoros I went that way, and check the `setup.cfg` only to understand that is the same as the guy next to me had(and he does not have my problems). Then I dive into the `pbr` scripts, and found the source of the exception in function `get_version`, in module `packaging.py`. When I reviewed this function I noticed that I can enforce this version by setting the environment variable **PBR_VERSION** to '0.1' (this is the version I had found in `setup.cfg` before). After this, there were no Exceptions, and unit testing (which I used `mock` for) WORKS!

Comment: That's reassuring! Good that you were able to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and in my case updating setuptools was the fix.
I've found the suggestion here:
https://github.com/testing-cabal/mock/issues/314

Before update I had setuptools 0.6c11 and I've updated to latest 39.2.0.

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

or actually in my case I had to download and install locally since production server has no connection to internet:

```
pip download setuptools

pip install setuptools-39.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```